# How to handle Discourse SSO when the authentication site allows users to change emails?

Tags: discourse

We use a Discourse SSO flow that we have implemented based on this guide: https://meta.discourse.org/t/official-single-sign-on-for-discourse-sso/13045

It has worked well for us. But now we want to allow users in our system to change their e-mail and this seems to lead to problems.

When I change the email of my user in our system, SSO to Discourse stops working.

> Login Error
>
> There is a problem with your account. Please contact the site's
>   administrator.

I guess that Discourse receives a payload with an email and a username that don't match and doesn't know what to do.

**What is a good way to handle this?**

The best idea I have come up with is to use the Discourse API to change the users email in Discourse to match that in out system before initiating SSO.

But I don't know if this is possible. Below is my failed attempt.

Here is my request:

```
https://forum-stage.{domain}.com/users/{username}/preferences/email

Headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

Body (as x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman):
email: testemail@testdomain.com
api_key: 75a...77d
api_username: system
```

And here is the response I receive

```
{
    "errors": [
        "You are not permitted to view the requested resource."
    ],
    "error_type": "invalid_access"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a way to handle changing e-mail addresses on the SSO provider side, because that is possible without problems when using Discourse as the SSO provider.

We have a setup where, for weird reasons, we have one Discourse site as the SSO provider and other Discourse sites as SSO clients. It is possible to change user e-mails in the Discourse SSO provider, and then during the next login these changes are synced to the SSO clients.

I did not investigate how this mechanism works exactly, but probably via the "external ID" scheme added for SSO purposes by Discourse to user records. You would have to check the payload of the next login after an e-mail address change in such an all-Discourse SSO system to see what exactly is going on, and then could do it similarly in your own implementation.